# What is the correct pattern for dependency injection in standard to be utilized in framework?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I am writing a dotnet standard library class that will contain an HttpClient that calls a web api method. I want the input/output classes available for ease of use to the caller. The projects consuming the package will be framework apps (4.7)

As far as I can tell the "correct" way to do that is to have a extension method taking an IServiceCollection which registers my client according to some known "defaults" and allows clients to pass in options.

I guess I'm wondering how that would get utilized in a framework app properly? So after I configure the service collection pipeline to know how to do things properly... How does the framework app ever get a ServiceCollection? Do i just make a static class that news up a ServiceCollection and stores the reference? Again to make that as easy as possible would I just include a static factory method in the library class to do that for the consumer? Something like this?

```
        public sealed class DependencyInjectionHelper
        {
            private static readonly Lazy<DependencyInjectionHelper> _instance = new Lazy<DependencyInjectionHelper>();

            public static DependencyInjectionHelper Instance => _instance.Value;

            public readonly IServiceCollection ServiceCollection;
            public readonly ServiceProvider ServiceProvider;
            private DependencyInjectionHelper()
            {
                ServiceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
                ServiceProvider = ServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
            }

            public MyHttpClient GetClient()
            {
                return ServiceProvider.GetService<MyHttpClient>();
            }
        }

        public static IServiceCollection AddMyClient(this IServiceCollection services, Action<MyClientOptions, IServiceProvider> configureOptions)
        {
            services.AddOptions();
            services.AddLogging();
            services.AddHttpClient<IMyClient, MyClient>().ConfigureHttpClient(client =>
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    
//configure baseaddress from options here somehow
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://someurl:5001/");

                if (!AppContext.TryGetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", out var enabled) || !enabled)
                {
                    //https://www.nimaara.com/beware-of-the-net-httpclient/
                    var servicePoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(client.BaseAddress);
                    int desiredLeaseTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds;
                    if (servicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout != desiredLeaseTimeout)
                    {
                        servicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = desiredLeaseTimeout;
                    }
                }
            });

            return services;
        }
```

Guess i'm looking for examples in the proper pattern to accomplish this. I understand dependency injection all the way through is probably the best way... but I can't just change monolithic apps to have it. So i want something flexible enough to be used if you have dependency injection, but super simple to consume out of the box.

Comment: All Microsoft.Extension packages are .NET Standard packages, so you don't need to write anything differently. You don't need any extra patterns or helpers. In fact, `DependencyInjectionHelper` breaks the dependency injection pattern and convers it into a Service Locator, which is *not* a good idea. With DI, all classes are created by the DI container, they don't call it directly. Classes/services should be written as if DI doesn't even exist. The DI container will create the appropriate instances for all dependencies.

Comment: If you check any of the DI, worker or console examples, you'll see that all classes are registered as services. A "main" class or multiple "service" classes are also registered and executed once the DI is set up. For workers and Background Services, the call to `Run()` will instantiate all `BackgroundService`-derived classes and call their `ExecuteAsync` method. For a console application, you can register a "main" class, instantiate it through DI in the `Main()` method and call its methods. For ASP.NET Core, this is done automatically

Comment: If I was writing a "new" app, I would use dependency injection from the ground up. in a Background service or something like was mentioned.

That is not the scenario though... I'm writing a new library project in dotnet standard. I need this library to be consumed in a 257k line of code windows service that's already written in framework. I'm not going to re architect that entire thing to use DI. I just want to be able to write a library to wrap an api call that is versatile and simple to use in my scenario, while also following best practice if it was going to be used in core.